# How would I get rid of this little popup + 1 Issue (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a photography website and I'm having some issues.

#### Issue 1:

Horizontal Scrolling
I found that there is a really annoying horizontal scrolling bar. I removed it with `overflow-x: hidden` in the CSS, but is there a way to get rid of it naturally? (Full code snippet at the end)
[image]

#### Issue 2:

Navbar
I'm using a Bootstrap Navbar with a dropdown link, but when I click the link, this shows up instead of the little popup:
Click [here](https://www.lunarr.cf/images/2022-09-22%2021-34-00.mp4) for the link to the video
(Sorry for using a third-party site, but its a video so you can understand.)
I did find, however, removing the `overflow-x: hidden` removes this issue but the horizontal scrolling still appears.

Thanks in advance
And here is the code snippet.
I also use jquery 2.1.4

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: #0d1b2e;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #014f82;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}

.hi {
  text-align: center;
  /* padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: Center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
*/
}


/*
.h1 > * {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
*/

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
}


/*
.h1:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-image: url(https://xitzdiamondx.github.io/assets/img/walpaper1.jpeg);
    background-position: center;
}

.h1:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top 0;
    width: 100%; height 100%;
}
*/

.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0.5)), url(https://www.lunarr.cf/images/wallpaper1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: Center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0.5)), url(https://xitzdiamondx.github.io/assets/img/wallpaper3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: Center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Ahadu Photo Studio</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark bg-gradient">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html">
        <img src="https://www.topseobrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/ahadu_icon.png" alt="Logo" width="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-center"> አሓዱ ፎቶ ስቱዲዮ
      </a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./index.html" class="nav-link active">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="" class="nav-link active">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Order
                </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10x15</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://www.notdiamond.cf/assets/js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="div1">
    <h2>Professional Photography Studio</h2>
    <br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="div2">
    <h2>I'm a Self-Taught Developer</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="loader-wrapper" style="display: none;">
    <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(window).on("load", function() {
      $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
    });
  </script>
  <div style="position: static !important;"></div>
  <div id="torrent-scanner-popup" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

## [Repo](https://github.com/AhaduStudio/ahadustudio.github.io/)

Comment: Check the li element of order menu. Seems like its getting a overflow-x rule somehow.. Inspect that with developer tool (inspect element) and hopefully you will find it..

Comment: Ohh I see, you have this here.. body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }... you really should remove it.. I understand that then you are getting the horizontal scrollbar.. That scrollbar might be for something else.. Can you upload your code somewhere so that we can check it?

Comment: Try removing  `body { width: 100vw;}` , (and the overflow: hidden)

Comment: Scroll bar appears because the content is wider than the container - make it so the content is not wider than the container and the scrollbar will disappear "naturally".   Removing bootstrap and starting from scratch *might* help as bootstrap tends to add numerous extra paddings/margins in places it has no right to.

Comment: @RakeshMehta I'll release it on GitHub
By the way, I downloaded Bootstrap for offline programming.
[Repo](https://github.com/AhaduStudio/ahadustudio.github.io/)